# Custom rules definition using drools

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, business-rules

Can I use Drools for a definition like below

```
> pay_type in(NB,CC) and (brand in (VISA,MASTER) or bank in(HDFC,CITI))

operations - and , or
keyword - in
tags - pay_type , brand , bank
```

I need to provide a java api with 3 inputs
`validateAgainstRule('NB', 'VISA', 'AXIS')` should return me `true;` and 
`validateAgainstRule('NB', 'AMEX', 'AXIS')` should return me `false;`

Can I achieve this using drools?

Comment: Providing the Java API you describe is a lot more work than the single rule Esteban described. Hopefully you need many more validation rules - for this single validation the use of an RBS (Drools) is an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need if you want to use Drools is a class model. A simplistic class model for your scenario could be:

```
public class Payment {
    private String payType;
    private String brand;
    private String bank;

    private boolean valid = false; //the initial state of a payment is invalid

    //getters an setters, of course
    //...
}
```

Then, for your use case, you need just a single rule:

```
rule "validate payment"
when
    $p: Payment(
        payType in ("NB", "CC") &&
        (brand in ("VISA", "MASTER") || bank in ("HDFC", "CITI"))
    )
then
   $p.setValid(true);
end
```

Given that, in your scenario, a payment is either valid or not, you don't need to create a different rule to mark payment objects as invalid.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Let me try this, since I am new to Drools its takes time for me to understand, thanks for your help

Comment: Can you direct me a good documentation where I can use an drools expression like above and validate an input dynamically. I am first time starting with drools and could not able to make a move

Comment: [Drools documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR4/drools-docs/html_single/) is a good starting point.

A better source of information could be [Drools 5.x developer guide book](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/drools-jboss-rules-5x-developer%E2%80%99s-guide). The update for Drools 6.x is already on its way.